# I can't import tkinter in Pycharm using the future package. Any suggestions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I am getting this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\me\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import future.moves.tkinter
  File "C:\Users\me\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\lib\site-packages\future\moves\tkinter\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from tkinter import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'
```

My code is

```
import future.moves.tkinter
```

I also tried

```
from future.moves import tkinter
```

Edit:
Install a new python with tkinter and set the interpretator to that one

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the future package you can just download the package it self and do `from tkinter import *`

to download the tkinter package you can either click the python packages label in the bottom center of the file or go to file ➜ settings ➜ your project ➜ python interpeter ➜ the plus sign over the package label ➜ and it will open a window and there you can search for tkinter

Comment: I tried that and got the same error message. Also which tkinter, there are about like 40.

Comment: Try import tkinter